# Портится память при освобождении динамического массива

Tags: c++

При удалении динамического массива arr получаю сообщение о том что HEAP CORRUPTION DETECTED, уже несколько дней сижу с этой проблемой и никак не дойду что здесь не так :с

```
class Matrix
{
public:
    int row;
    int str;
    vector<TYPE*> matrix;
    TYPE *arr;
}
```

Проблемная функция

```
void Fill(string fName)
{
    arr = new TYPE[str];
    ifstream f(fName.c_str());
    if (!f.is_open())
    {           
        cout << "Enter the elements:" << endl;
        for (int i = 0; i < str; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < row; j++)
            {               
                cin >> arr[j];                  
            }
            matrix.push_back(arr);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < str; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < row; j++)
            {
                f >> arr[j];
            }
            matrix.push_back(arr);
        }
    }
    f.close();
    delete[] arr;
}
```

Comment: TYPE это что за тип?

Comment: @pavel это шаблон

Comment: а падает навсех типах или только на каких-то?

Comment: Чему равен row? Гарантировано ли он не превышает str?

Comment: @AntonShchyrov row = 3 и str = 2, а почему row не должно превышать str?

Comment: @WholeHog а ошибка прям на этой строчке (`delete[] arr`)?

Comment: @АлексейСаровский да, именно на ней

Comment: @AntonShchyrov порча памяти действительно происходит только если row>str, пытаюсь понять почему

Comment: @WholeHog потому что размер вы выделили `[str]`, а надо `[row]`. Вы же заполняете по `j < row`

Comment: @АлексейСаровский вот я дурилка. Спасибо!

Comment: Какой в этом коде в принципе может быть смысл, если он заносит в `matrix` указатель на массив, а затем сразу уничтожает этот массив нафиг? В `matrix` остается сидеть "мертвый" указатель.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Создание `arr` выполняется единожды, затем он `str` раз заполняется и сохраняется в `martix`. Помимо неверного размера для выделяемой памяти (о чем написали в комментариях), тут еще и банальная ошибка с перезаписью данных. Создание arr нужно перенести внутри цикла `for (int i = ...)`, а `delete[]` убрать в принципе и вызывать только в деструкторе для каждого элемента `matrix`.